# Python can't read a file in my python project. How can I solve it?

Tags: python

My code below, Python can't read my file:

```html
f = open('./resource/review.txt','r')
```

The error is as in [photo: `Errno 2: No such file in directory`](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RoVu2.png).

Comment: you exact file location ? because this way you can access file.

Comment: The error is with executing your python file, not with opening the file inside the python script. Since you're using \ in your path when running the file, which is used to escape the character following it, it only sees the character (and not the directory separator - you can see this from the error message). Use `/` instead of \ when letting the IDE run the file, and it should at least run the script.

Comment: As I keep looking, it seems to be a problem with Python or vscode itself. I just implemented a print() in the new directory for testing, but Python is not reading it.

Comment: Please put the actual text of the error in your question, not in image link: `Errno 2: No such file in directory`. If you search on that on SO you will find many duplicates (6778 in fact), it simply means that that file cannot be found, in the directory in which you're executing (which might not be the directory the Python script is in or that you think you're in, if you're using an IDE).

Comment: Thank you for pointing out my inexperienced question!

Comment: Seems to be a problem with your IDE. As you see in in the photo when trying to execute your python code it strips all `\` signs of the path of the python file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try \ instead of /

```
f = open('.\\resource\\review.txt','r')
content = f.read()
print(content)
```

Comment: As I keep looking, it seems to be a problem with Python or vscode itself. I just implemented a print() in the new directory for testing, but Python is not reading it.

Answer (score 0):

Because the file is not located at the same folder as your script you need to go back one folder.
In order to do that tou need '..' (double dot) and not one, this will indicate to go back a folder relative to the current path.

Answer (score 0):

The message `Errno 2: No such file in directory` simply means that **your relative pathname to your file cannot be found in the directory in which you're executing** (which might not be the directory the Python script is in or that you think you're in, if you're using an IDE).

So to see what directory your Python is actually running in, do:

```
print(f'current directory is: {os.getcwd()}')
```